# How to download user uploaded files in another page? - PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am looking forward to download a user uploaded files (e.g PDF or jpeg saved in a MySQL database) on another page (e.g admin side).

I have followed some tutorials on youtube but none of them seem to provide a clear demonstration of what I want to achieve.

My question is, do anyone know a reference about it or can you provide a simple example if ever you've achieved it before?

I'm rather new to PHP and MySQL, glad if you could help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
<?php
$fileName = 'myfile.jpg';
$fileContent = ''; // fetch file content from mysql

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8''".rawurlencode($fileName));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileContent));

print $fileContent;
```

If filename is always ASCII chars you can use just `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');`